# Notepad++ permanent line marking?

Tags: notepad++

I need to mark certain lines in Notepad++ permanently.
They offer a line marking (blue dots in the picture below), but I can't save the marked state. What are my options?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> They offer a line marking (blue dots in the picture below), but I can't save the marked state.

The "blue dots" are called **bookmarks**.

To save the `bookmarks` you need to enable `sessions`.

To enable `sessions`:

- menu *Settings* → *Preferences*
- select *Backup*
- enable *Remember current session for next launch*

[image]

---

#### Notepad++ doesn't even give me the option to save when I add bookmarks.

Use menu *File* → *Save Session...*

---

#### Changes not automatically saved

> Here are a few ways changes may not get saved to the session file.
>
> - If you change bookmarks or folded lines via the menu or a keyboard shortcut then terminate Notepad++ without doing anything that
>     would cause the session to be saved. This is because a plugin cannot
>     detect those events. Clicking in the bookmark or fold margins is
>     detected.
> - If you close a file then immediately terminate Notepad++ (see sessionSaveDelay in Manual Settings).
> - If you do anything that results in a change to one of the following then immediately terminate Notepad++ (see settingsSavePoll
>     in Manual Settings).
>
>   - bookmarks
>   - folded lines
>   - filters
>   - favorites
>   - sort order
>   - dialog window sizes
>   - default session name

---

Source [Session Manager help](http://mfoster.com/npp/SessionMgr.html)

Comment: It works, but only if I exit Notepad without exiting the relevant tab. If I exit the tab for the file everything is wiped. I need a more sturdy solution for permament line marking.

Comment: I just tested. Closed all tabs. Closed and restarted notepad++. Reopened a file. The bookmarks are still present.

Comment: As a matter of fact notepad doesn't even give me the option to save when I add bookmarks. It's as if nothing was changed in data.

Comment: Use `file` > `save session`

Comment: Thank you! I saved the session to a new file, unfortunately I have to load the session every time I X out the tab. Is there a way to way automate this?

Comment: @Manumit I don't know of any way to automate this. I don't normally close my tabs :/